# Invalid Column Name - Column Does Exist

Tags: sql-server

I have a table to which I added a new column, as such:

```
ALTER TABLE [Invoice].[Invoice] ADD [DaysToPay] int
GO
ALTER TABLE [Invoice].[Invoice] ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_Invoice_DaysToPay]  DEFAULT ((30)) FOR [DaysToPay]
GO
UPDATE [Invoice].[Invoice] SET [DaysToPay] = 30
GO
ALTER TABLE [Invoice].[Invoice] ALTER COLUMN [DaysToPay] int NOT NULL
GO
```

If I now do `SELECT * FROM [Invoice].[Invoice]` I get an `Invalid column name 'DaysToPay'` error. I get this error whether I run the statement through SSMS or any other means (via code).

The same error occurs with or without the column when I select specific columns. e.g. `SELECT [InvoiceID] FROM [Invoice].[Invoice]`.

I have closed SSMS and restarted the SQL service. Still the same error.

The column was added under the same user that is getting the error and that same user is the owner of the schema.

Both these statements return 0 rows:

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'DaysToPay'

SELECT *
FROM sys.columns 
WHERE Name = N'DaysToPay'
```

I've tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> but I don't think it's a SSMS thing and it made no difference.

The database is not replicated.

I ran a `DBCC OPENTRAN` are there were none active.

I have since removed the column (manually using the designer in SSMS) and I still get the same error. The table shows correctly in the SSMS designer (as it did prior to me manually removing it).

Any ideas other than dropping and re-creating the table?

EDIT:
The rest of the script that was run is as follows (I have removed certain columns so as not to identify):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [Invoice].[Invoice_Save] (
    @InvoiceID int,
    @TypeID int,
    @InvoiceNumber int,
    @InvoiceDate datetime,
    @DatePaid datetime,
    @PaymentEnteredBy int,
    @AmountPaid float,
    @PaymentTypeID int,
    @HasVAT bit,
    @VATRate float,
    @TranslationPercentageCharge float,
    @IsVoid bit,
    @VoidDate datetime,
    @VoidBy int,
    @DateSent datetime,
    @SentBy int,
    @PurchaseOrderNumber varchar(100),
    @BillingContact varchar(255),
    @BillingAddress varchar(MAX),
    @BillingContactEmail nvarchar(255),
    @BillingContactTelNo varchar(50),
    @Notes varchar(MAX),
    @CompanyID int,
    @DaysToPay int,
    @DateCreated datetime,
    @CreatedBy int,
    @LastUpdated datetime,
    @LastUpdatedBy int
)

AS

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [Invoice].[Invoice] WHERE [InvoiceID] = @InvoiceID)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [Invoice].[Invoice] ([TypeID], [InvoiceNumber], [InvoiceDate], , [DatePaid], [PaymentEnteredBy], [AmountPaid], [PaymentTypeID], [HasVAT], [VATRate], [TranslationPercentageCharge], [IsVoid], [VoidDate], [VoidBy], [DateSent], [SentBy], [PurchaseOrderNumber], [BillingContact], [BillingAddress], [BillingContactEmail], [BillingContactTelNo], [Notes], [CompanyID], [DaysToPay], [DateCreated], [CreatedBy], [LastUpdated], [LastUpdatedBy])
        VALUES (@TypeID, @InvoiceNumber, @InvoiceDate, @DatePaid, @PaymentEnteredBy, @AmountPaid, @PaymentTypeID, @HasVAT, @VATRate, @TranslationPercentageCharge, @IsVoid, @VoidDate, @VoidBy, @DateSent, @SentBy, @PurchaseOrderNumber, @BillingContact, @BillingAddress, @BillingContactEmail, @BillingContactTelNo, @Notes, @CompanyID, @DaysToPay, @DateCreated, @CreatedBy, @LastUpdated, @LastUpdatedBy)

        SELECT MAX([InvoiceID]) AS MaxID FROM [Invoice].[Invoice]
    END
    ELSE
        UPDATE [Invoice].[Invoice]
        SET [TypeID] = @TypeID,
        [InvoiceNumber] = @InvoiceNumber,
        [InvoiceDate] = @InvoiceDate,
        [DatePaid] = @DatePaid,
        [PaymentEnteredBy] = @PaymentEnteredBy,
        [AmountPaid] = @AmountPaid,
        [PaymentTypeID] = @PaymentTypeID,
        [HasVAT] = @HasVAT,
        [VATRate] = @VATRate,
        [TranslationPercentageCharge] = @TranslationPercentageCharge,
        [IsVoid] = @IsVoid,
        [VoidDate] = @VoidDate,
        [VoidBy] = @VoidBy,
        [DateSent] = @DateSent,
        [SentBy] = @SentBy,
        [PurchaseOrderNumber] = @PurchaseOrderNumber,
        [BillingContact] = @BillingContact,
        [BillingAddress] = @BillingAddress,
        [BillingContactEmail] = @BillingContactEmail,
        [BillingContactTelNo] = @BillingContactTelNo,
        [Notes] = @Notes,
        [CompanyID] = @CompanyID,
        [DaysToPay] = @DaysToPay,
        [DateCreated] = @DateCreated,
        [CreatedBy] = @CreatedBy,
        [LastUpdated] = @LastUpdated,
        [LastUpdatedBy] = @LastUpdatedBy
        WHERE [InvoiceID] = @InvoiceID
GO
```

Comment: What happens if you fully qualify all of those queries with the database name?

Comment: youre sure you're connected to the correct DB?

Comment: What about when you run `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Invoice'`? Check the schema *and* column names, see anything out of the ordinary?

Comment: @TabAlleman Same error :( `SELECT * FROM [MyDB].[Invoice].[Invoice]`

Comment: @Igor It shows in the list (now that I have added it back using the script - I still get the error though)

Comment: In that case, can you post a script that reproduces the problem?  I can't help but think that there is nothing wrong, and you are just missing something that isn't part of the code you posted.  How could a simple `SELECT * ...` produce an invalid column error?   There has to be more to this than you are telling us.

Comment: Are you working in a transaction that has not been committed yet? Is the select statement from within the same SSMS session?

Comment: @TabAlleman The rest of the script is an `ALTER PROCEDURE` I will add it to the post...

Comment: @Igor It was not in a transaction

Comment: @TabAlleman @Igor I have fixed (**masked**) the problem. I did a `TRUNCATE TABLE [Invoice].[Invoice]` and now I can do a `SELECT *` from it. As to why it happened, I am baffled! Like you say Tab, how? I have run countless similar statements before with no problem. My concern is what happens when I run in production - I won't get away with a `TRUNCATE` there! Fingers crossed!